# How to connect two endpoints in a class with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, rest, syntax-error

I would like to connect to two endpoints of an API. I am using GEO database API where to access the country details. I need the id passed in countries endpoint. For this I would like to do it dynamically, taking the code provided by this API and passing this code to the other endpoint. In this case, I'm using the same template for both. Sorry if what I say is confusing, I'm lost. In this case, the countries endpoint is connecting normally and the one with the id is returning null

Endpoint: geo/countries **TO**
Endpoint: geo/countries/{IdCountry}

### Class connection

```
public class Connection {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/";
    private static final String API_KEY = "";
    private static final String API_HOST = "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com";

    public static String connectHttp(String end_Point) {
        String return_api = null;
        String url_amount = BASE_URL + end_Point;
        System.out.println(url_amount);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_amount);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-RapidAPI-Key", API_KEY);
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-RapidAPI-Host", API_HOST);
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                return_api = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Error, code of return: " + responseCode);

            connection.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
        return return_api;
    }
}
```

### Class for to parse json

```
public class CountryFetcher {

    private Handler handler;
    private OnCountryFetchListener listener;

    public CountryFetcher(Handler handler, OnCountryFetchListener listener) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void fetchCountries() {
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("CountryFetcherThread");
        handlerThread.start();

        Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = Connection.connectHttp("geo/countries");

                if (result != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject countryJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String code = countryJson.getString("code");
                            String name = countryJson.getString("name");
                            Country country = new Country(code, name);

                            String countryDetailsResult = Connection.connectHttp("geo/countries/" + country.getCode());

                            if (countryDetailsResult != null) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject countryDetailsJson = new JSONObject(countryDetailsResult);
                                    JSONObject countryDataJson = countryDetailsJson.getJSONObject("data");


                                    String callingCode = countryDataJson.getString("callingCode");
                                    String flagImageUri = countryDataJson.getString("flagImageUri");
                                    int numRegions = countryDataJson.getInt("numRegions");
                                    String wikiDataId = countryDataJson.getString("wikiDataId");


                                    country.setCallingCode(callingCode);
                                    country.setFlagImageUri(flagImageUri);
                                    country.setNumRegions(numRegions);
                                    country.setWikiDataId(wikiDataId);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            countries.add(country);
                        }

                        if (listener != null) {
                            listener.CountryFetchSuccess(countries);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if (listener != null) {
                            listener.CountryFetchError();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.CountryFetchError();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface OnCountryFetchListener {
        void CountryFetchSuccess(List<Country> countries);
        void CountryFetchError();
    }
}
```

### Model of Country

```
public class Country {

    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String callingCode;
    private String flagImageUri;
    private int numRegions;
    private String wikiDataId;

    public Country(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCallingCode() {
        return callingCode;
    }

    public void setCallingCode(String callingCode) {
        this.callingCode = callingCode;
    }

    public String getFlagImageUri() {
        return flagImageUri;
    }

    public void setFlagImageUri(String flagImageUri) {
        this.flagImageUri = flagImageUri;
    }

    public int getNumRegions() {
        return numRegions;
    }

    public void setNumRegions(int numRegions) {
        this.numRegions = numRegions;
    }

    public String getWikiDataId() {
        return wikiDataId;
    }

    public void setWikiDataId(String wikiDataId) {
        this.wikiDataId = wikiDataId;
    }
}
```

I don't know if I should put the endpoint request inside another loop in the parse class.

I tried to make separate method with a loop of its own, similar to what I did with the first endpoint. But it was also returning null.

**I would like to know how to fix this error.**

Comment: I don't see where you are using templates at all. Only that you manually convert JSON objects to your model class. IMHO you should consider automatic model parsing from JSON like it is provided by Jackson. That would simplify your code a lot, just the model class and directly parse it from the response data InputStream using Jackson. Nobody really wants to pars all the JSON data structure smanually.